# Why I can't edit repository-wiki page anymore?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had let indexing my ros-repository and edited the wiki page. But now I can't edit it anymore. It even says: "You are not allowed to view this page."

I am very confused and don't know how to be able to edit it again or even see it.

Is there a way to be able to edit it again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29119/why-i-can%27t-edit-repository-wiki-page-anymore?/) by [rikushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1913/rikushan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rikushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1913/rikushan/) on 2012-03-05**:
maybe it's because of the acl line? I think I did not delete or edit it. Anyway, what to do now?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-05**:
Can you please provide more details about what repo and what url you're having trouble with?

**Comment by [rikushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1913/rikushan/) on 2012-03-05**:
sure. it's this repo: agas-ros-pkg
and I'm having trouble with that url: http://www.ros.org/wiki/agas-ros-pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you alluded to in your comments (very important to put this sort of information in the question), there was an acl on the page.  None of our templates have an acl on them, so I don't know how this otherwise would have gotten there.  I went ahead and removed the acl.  This takes a lot of extra time to undo on our part, so please do not use acls.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rikushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1913/rikushan/) on 2012-03-06**:
okay, sorry for the circumstances. I used the repo template which provided the acl line. I will make sure not to use acls anymore. thank you very much!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-06**:
Can you link to the template you used? I'm not aware of a repo template and want to eliminate any acls.

**Comment by [rikushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1913/rikushan/) on 2012-03-06**:
I think I mixed things up. I used this template: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ProjectTemplate . It wasn't obvious to me which template I had to use for the repo wikipage if any is needed. So the words project and repository were more similar to me than reopsitory and package, why I even used the template

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-07**:
@rikushan: if this is an acceptable answer to your question, please mark it accepted by clicking on the checkbox to the left.  That way others don't keep visiting this post.